# Transfer ownership of unique_ptr back and forth between controller and view

Tags: c++, model-view-controller, unique-ptr

For a project we need to make a 'game' and use a library we got to create a world, this library gives us a vector of unique pointers. However, this vector is gotten by the controller class, and to visualize the world, we also have a view class. Since I am new to unique pointers, i was wondering if it is considered 'bad practice' to take a vector of unique pointers, transfer ownership, visualize and then return the vector to transfer ownership back again?

```
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Tile>> TerminalView::updateWorld(std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Tile>> world)
     {
        //use the vector and return it
     }
```

this would be a function in the view class.

Comment: you can also take `reference`, `raw pointers` and `week_ptr`(with `shared_ptr`) without transfer ownership. (and `vector` of `unique_ptr` seems not necessary here, `vector<Tile>` is good enough)

Comment: Why not just pass the whole vector as reference? No ownership problem then...

Comment: **void** `TerminalView::updateWorld(std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Tile>>` **&** `world`

Comment: @appleapple we can't adapt the library, so we are stuck with unique pointers (is part of the challenge)

Comment: @Aconcagua Thank you, I will try it this way, but I need to use the values of the unique pointers (Tile) to get the position of the tiles (function in Tile), will I be able to do this without owner transfer?

Comment: @YFrickx Well, sure why not? "ownership" in this sense is not a matter of possessing an object, but rather of responsibility (to delete the object, mainly).